# How to use an ARG variable in a RUN command of a Dockerfile?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, dockerfile

I'm writing a Dockerfile, in which I want the python version and the requirements file to be configurable. It is as follows:

```
ARG VERSION=3.9
ARG REQUIREMENTS_FILE="../requirements.txt"

FROM python:$VERSION

RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN python3 -m pip install -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE

CMD python3 -m pip freeze
```

However, when I build the image (`docker build -t myimage:1.0 --build-arg VERSION=3.10 --build-arg REQUIREMENTS_FILE="../requirements.txt" .`), I get the following error:

```
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN python3 -m pip install -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE                                                                   0.6s
------                                                                                                                                  
 > [3/3] RUN python3 -m pip install -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE:                                                                              
0.539                                                                                                                                   
0.539 Usage:                                                                                                                            
0.539   /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...                             
0.539   /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...                              
0.539   /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
0.539   /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
0.539   /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...
0.539 
0.539 -r option requires 1 argument
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     
   6 |     RUN python3 -m ensurepip
   7 | >>> RUN python3 -m pip install -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE
   8 |     
   9 |     CMD python3 -m pip freeze
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python3 -m pip install -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/lgd2p5onypc74hsljarhv7a9o
```

The URL leads to the same error printed before.

I build this image from a shell script, but the error is the same from CLI . I tried with ${REQUIREMENTS_FILE} as well, and with an array: `RUN ["python3", "-m", "pip", "install", "-r", $REQUIREMENTS_FILE]`, nothing worked.
Is what I am trying to do even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Args are scoped to the stage where they are defined, and at the top of the file, they are only defined for the FROM lines. So you would need to move it down:

```
ARG VERSION=3.9

FROM python:$VERSION

ARG REQUIREMENTS_FILE="../requirements.txt"
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN python3 -m pip install -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE

CMD python3 -m pip freeze
```

Then you'll encounter the next issue, which is that the file doesn't exist inside the image. You'll want to learn about the build context and COPY command for more on that.

> I tried with ... an array: `RUN ["python3", "-m", "pip", "install", "-r", $REQUIREMENTS_FILE]`

That will never work since docker doesn't expand build args in a RUN step, it just passes them as environment variables. You need a shell to expand environment variables, and the json array syntax, aka exec syntax, explicitly runs the step without a shell.

Comment: It was indeed the issue, thank you ! 

However I tried copying the file (`COPY $REQUIREMENTS_FILE requirements.txt
`, and the variable IS evaluated to `../requirements-3.10.txt`) and get: `ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref f7183e68-406b-4ed0-bfef-63b05b2c60eb::lamwhx6ee7bm6k89uqqm4bp89: "/requirements-3.10.txt": not found`

Comment: You can never `COPY` files from a parent or sibling directory, only the directory named as the build-context directory and its children.

Comment: Okay, and is the path dependent of the Dockerfile location or the "current directory" of the shell that started the build ?

Comment: The path is relative to the build context, which is an argument passed to the `docker build` command. Typically that's the current directory and same directory as the Dockerfile.

Comment: More details on the build context can be found at https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/